# react-app-rewired customise default start url

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-app-rewired

I have installed react-app-rewired.
In the package.json I have set

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts",
}
```

When I run

```
npm start
```

It opens a browser window on localhost:3000
I would like to open it to a specific URL:port that I have set in my hosts file.
This will allow my local front end app to contact a remote API without throwing a CORS issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is webpack-dev-server related

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    open: ['/my-page'],
  },
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen

```
// config-overrides.js

module.exports = () => ({
  devServer: (c) => {
    return () => ({open: ['/newer-url']});
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting ```options.open should be {String|Boolean|Object}``` error with your config-overrides.js example.